# React - PUBLIC_URL is still undefined after setting it

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment-variables

I try to setup my PUBLIC_URL for my serviceworker configuration and befor bundling the app I set my PUBLIC_URL in the webpack.config.js:

#### webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = (env) => {

    const isProduction = env.production === true;
    const isDevelopment = env.development === true;

    process.env.NODE_ENV = isProduction ? 'production' : isDevelopment && 'development';
    process.env.PUBLIC_URL = '/';

    return {...config}
}
```

I even created a `.env` file with `PUBLIC_URL=/` but nothing seems to work when I log the PUBLIC_URL in my service.worker register it is still undefined:

```
export function register(config) {
    console.log(process.env.PUBLIC_URL)

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location.href);
        if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
            return;
        }

        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

            if (isLocalhost) {
                checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);
                navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
                    console.log(
                        'This web app is being served cache-first by a service worker.');
                });
            } else {
                registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am trying to run the app with the webpack-dev-server and also tried it by generating the dist folder and openend the index.html folder up. Does anyone know the reason why?

Comment: it seems that you are having the same problem with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55663896/how-to-secure-security-access-key-in-react-js-application/55664119#55664119. Please refer to my answer. you case is probably same with webpack solution I mentioned

Comment: That helped me your solutions works with the dotenv package perfectly fine (I am using the webpack approach - not CRA). Thanks!