# how to secure security_access_key in react js application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, environment-variables

I don't want to directly import security_access_key in my application due to security reason.

I tried accessing environment variable like below

step 1:

added security_access_key to .env file

```
 security_access_key=abc123
```

step 2:

access it in App.js

```
console.log(process.env.security_access_key)
```

But getting value undefined.

Suggest any solution if anyone knows.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using create react app then you can use **.env** file in you root of you project.
  Add a file like .`env.development` inside add values like this

```
REACT_APP_SERVER_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:3000
```

make sure to add `REACT_APP_` as the prefix. inside the application you can access it

```
process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_ENDPOINT
```

Comment: still getting undefined value

Comment: getting process.env as {}

Comment: @kalyani_jamunkar are you using create react app?

Comment: Yes i am using create react app

Comment: @kalyani_jamunkar did you restart it after adding the values in `.env.development` ?. what is your create-react-app version?.

Comment: react-app version is ^16.7.0.

Comment: Do i need to add anything in webpack.config.dev

Comment: I added  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
           "process.env":{
           'REACT_APP_SERVER_ENDPOINT': JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_ENDPOINT)
         }
       })

Answer (score 0):

4 simple steps to get it working

1) `npm install dotenv --save`

2) Next add the following line to your app.

`require('dotenv').config()`

3) Then create a .env file at the root directory of your application and add the variables to it.

//contents of .env

`REACT_APP_API_KEY = 'my-secret-api-key'`

4) Finally, add .env to your .gitignore file so that Git ignores it and it never ends up on GitHub.

Note:- You need to restart application after adding variable in .env file and use "REACT_APP_" before variable name if you are creating react application using "create-react-app".

Answer (score 0):

- if you are using create react app then use the solution recommended by TRomesh by adding REACT_APP_params, it is the recommended way by create react app https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables.
- if you are using Webpack then you can use DefinePlugin to access that params

  //webpack.config.js
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.security_access_key': JSON.stringify(process.env.security_access_key),
    }),

then you can access process.env.security_access_key from your react app